# Bootstrap not working after Rails migration to 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a working Rails 4.0 + Bootstrap 2.3 application. Now I want to update to Rails 4.1.
After updating the gems and starting the server, I receive this message:

```
Sass::SyntaxError - File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-responsive.
```

It point to a line in `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss` where I have this:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

Both files are in the `assets/stylesheets` folder. When I remove the last import, the application starts, but I miss a lot of styling. What is going wrong here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 mistakes with this: first I did a `bundle update` instead of `bundle update rails`, so that all gems where updated, also the bootstrap and sass related gems. The second error was that I didn't have specific version numbers for the bootstrap and sass related gems in my `Gemfile`.

The solution was simple: remove the branch, create a new one, check `Gemfile.lock` for the current versions of all bootstrap and sass related gems and add these to `Gemfile`. Then do a `bundle update rails` and sit back and enjoy!